# How can I execute a php script on an android device?

Tags: java, php, android, adobe

The php script is on the android device itself and I need to run it on the device. I have downloaded a few php server apps from playstore and they work fine. But I have to implement this method inside my app so I cannot use another app to perform the server operations.

Actual problem:- So i have this [Adobe HDS script](https://github.com/K-S-V/Scripts/blob/master/AdobeHDS.php) and there is no java variant of this script.

Comment: Did you check http://www.phpforandroid.net/ ?

Comment: Yes I have already tried but no luck.
Does not seem to run php scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the three options I can think of.

**1) local execution with sl4a**

As far as I know, the only solution solution to execute scripting languages on Android devices (such as Python, Ruby or PHP) is [sl4a](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a), whose PHP support is provided by [PHP for Android](http://www.phpforandroid.net/doku.php). However it doesn't seem to be actively maintained.

**2) server-side execution**

You could host your script on a server and call it from the device through a HTTP request.

**3) porting to Java**

If your script is simple you could try to translate it into Java.